# define sub select query once only for multiple selects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I m writing a select query where i have to write the same sub query in two place

```
select e.MasterAccNumber from (
select MasterAccNumber from ACE_AccsLevelTran where CAST(timstmp as DATE) = '02/06/2013' 
union all
select m.AccountNumber from ACE_InvLevelTran i left join ACE_InvLevelMaster m i.MasterInvNumber=m.InvoiceNo 
where CAST(i.timstmp as date) ='02/06/2013' ) as e where e.MasterAccNumber not in( 
select e.MasterAccNumber from e group by e.MasterAccNumber having COUNT( e.MasterAccNumber) > 1 )
```

here in the last sub query the parser cannot understand the object e

```
select e.MasterAccNumber from e group by e.MasterAccNumber having COUNT( e.MasterAccNumber) > 1
```

how to write such that i do not define "e" multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select MasterAccNumber from 
(
select MasterAccNumber from ACE_AccsLevelTran where CAST(timstmp as DATE) = '02/06/2013' 
union all
select m.AccountNumber from ACE_InvLevelTran i 
left join ACE_InvLevelMaster m i.MasterInvNumber=m.InvoiceNo 
where CAST(i.timstmp as date) ='02/06/2013' 
)  e
group by MasterAccNumber 
having COUNT( MasterAccNumber) < 2
```